# How do I correctly position two connectors that must be spaced precisely while soldering?

Tags: connector, soldering, spacing

I am having someone else assemble some very small boards I designed. There are two board-to-board Molex slimstack connectors that must be spaced precisely (3 mm center-to-center), in order to mate with another commercially available board with the corresponding pair of connectors. The assembler has requested a "**mating gauge**" to hold the two connectors in place while soldering, to be removed after.

This seems logical, but I can't find any reference to a soldering "gauge" through google.  Anyone know what this is or how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to provide a sample of the mating board for the assemblers to use to help position the connectors on your board.

You could make a custom board with the mating connectors, but then you have the problem of getting those connectors in the correct position to hold the connectors on your "real" board in the correct position to mate with the commercial board.  (then there's the question of how accurately the connectors on the commercial board are positioned - does the manufacturer expect the board to connect to another board, or just to cables?  If he expects cables, then there is little need for his connectors to be precisely positioned.)